# Determining the location of a GTK widget on-screen to create a relevant popup window

Tags: popup, gtk

I have a button labeled import (down arrow) and I am trying to determine it's location so I can create a popup menu to say 1. from device 2. from folder.

I can't seem to find anymore than allocation in the api docs, which is relative to the application window. Please help, I will send imaginary cookies ^_^.

using PyGI if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer before but couldn't self answer yet.

The process is as follows:

1. determine the location of the GdkWindow, which does not contain the window decorations.
   : gdk_window_x, gdk_window_y
2. determine the location of the widget relative to it's GdkWindow
   : widget_x, widget_y

   `x = gdk_window_x + widget_x`

   `y = gdk_window_y + widget_y`

as everything in the graphics world measures from top left (unless your weird :-)), you now have the location of the top left pixel of your widget.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the position of the window relative to the screen using `window.get_position()`. Since you already know how to get the position of the button relative to the window, it should be a matter of adding up both to get the coordinates (relative to the screen) in which to place the popup.

Comment: Thanks I worked this out last night (but couldn't post an answer to my question), it's almost correct.  You need to get the location of the GdkWindow not the GtkWindow because the location of the widget is relative to the GtkWindow.